# Get directory structure from zip with Perl

Tags: perl, zip, archive

How can I get the directory structure of a zip file with perl using [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive%3a%3aZip)?
I've tried different method combinations but with no success.

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: You run the risk of having your question closed if you don't show that you have made some effort by showing your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/Archive%3a%3aZip)?

```
$!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Archive::Zip;

my $z = Archive::Zip::->new;
$z->read(shift);
say for $z->memberNames;
```

Comment: Yes I did read it and tried it out, from the documentation you've mentioned it: memberNames()

    Return a list of the (internal) file names of the zip members
it's a list of file names, not necessarily directory structure like Dir1 contains Dir1a and Dir1b (Dir1/Dir1a, Dir1/Dir1b, Dir2/Dir2a ..etc )

Comment: @AndreiDoanca: What data structure do you expect then?

Comment: something like @dirs=qw( ./ ./Dir1 ./Dir1/subDirA ./Dir1/subDirB ./Dir2 ./Dir2/subDirA ./Dir2/subDirb) and so on, with or without the './' but just directory names, I can get that with a grep on the list that memberNames return, but I was hoping for a method already in Archive::Zip module

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Archive::Zip installed, and it's been a long, long time since I've last used it.

Are you familiar with Object Oriented Perl? You didn't specify what you previously did. I know many people who aren't familiar with Object Oriented Perl (which is unfortunately the vast majority of people who use Perl) find Perl's Object Oriented syntax to be confusing.

To use `Archive::Zip`, you need to create an `Archive::Zip` object that will contain all of the information of the archive you're attempting to read via the [new](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm#Archive%3a%3aZip_Methods) constructor.

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new( $archive_to_read );

# Always check to see if the object was created!
if ( not defined $zip ) {
    die qq(Could not open "$archive_to_read");
}
```

This will open your `$archive_to_read` Zip file as the class object `$zip`.

Now, you can get all of the members of your archive with the [members or memberNames](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm#Zip_Archive_Accessors) method. The `members` will return a list of *members*, but these are member *objects* and not simply the names of members. The `memberNames` method will return a list of the names of the members. I don't know if this includes the directories or not. Again, you didn't specify what you tried, so I don't know if you tried this and didn't get what you wanted.

```
#Returns a list of member objects
my @member_list = $zip->members;

#May do what you want. I don't know if dir names are included.
my @member_names = $zip->memberNames;
```

If `memberNames` doesn't do it, you can take your list of *member objects* and use the [Member Operations](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm#MEMBER_OPERATIONS) to pull out the information from each member object:

```
for my $member ( @member_list ) {
    my $file_name = $member->FileName;
    print qq(File "$file_name" is in "$archive_to_read"\n);
}
```

Again, it's been a long while since I used `Archive::Zip`, so I can't vouch if this is 100% accurate.  It would have been easier if you've provided some more information why you were having trouble. Did you understand the basics of using `Archive::Zip`? Did you use a particular method, and not get the information you wanted?

One thing I would highly recommend is that if you don't know Object Oriented Perl, to learn it. Perl contains a [tutorial on Object Oriented Perl syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) and how it works. It's the way most modern Perl modules now work in Perl.

If you do understand Object Oriented Perl syntax, remember that [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is your friend. It will help you understand the data you're reading and whether what you are looking at. You should ***never*** use this information to directly manipulate the object, but it'll give you an idea what is stored in the object and what other object types might be hidden in it.

Once more: People on Stackoverflow want to help, but aren't mind readers. We need to know exactly what issues you're having. Did you even try to use `Archive::Zip`? Do you understand the basic ways Object Oriented perl syntax works, and if not, is this what was confusing you? Did you try the `members` method and get frustrated that it didn't produce what you want? The more we know, the more we can help.

You said you tried using `Archive::Zip`, but didn't show us what you tried. Next time, let us know what your code looked like and what problems you were having.

Comment: Hi David, great answer, to be more specific I hoped that Archive::Zip has a method that returns a list of all directories from an archive. But in the end membersMatching($someName) and grep that list. Thanks again

Comment: @AndreiDoanca Ther is a `isDirectory` method for a member. If the _member object_ is `$member`, you could run `if ( $member->isDirectory )` on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `memberNames` that returns *all* of the members of the zip archive. Extracting all the directory members is simple as they end with a slash.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip;

my $file = 'myfile.zip';

my $z = Archive::Zip->new($file);
my @zipdirs = grep m|/$|, $z->memberNames;
print "$_\n" for @zipdirs;
```

---

As Sinan says, it is probably more correct to check for `isDirectory` on each archive member. This probably produces identical results to the above.

```
my @zipdirs = map $_->fileName, grep $_->isDirectory, $zip->members;
```

Comment: Well, you could just invoke `isDirectory()` on each member.

Comment: Hi Borodin, thanks for the code, my final solution was something resembling your code. I just took all the members and checked if they had a file name and extension, and greped the members who what and ending backslash. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
my @dirs = grep $_->isDirectory, $zip->members;
```

Comment: Hi Sinan, thanks for the code, simple and great. Best regards